# List of List to ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, k-means, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use kmeans clustering in scipy, exactly the one present here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans

What I am trying to do is to convert a list of list such as the following:

```
data without_x[
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20.0, 1.0, 48.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1224.0, 125.5, 3156.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.5, 56.0, 41.5, 85.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1495.0, 3496.5, 2715.0, 5566.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

into a ndarry in order to use it with the Kmeans method. When I try to convert the list of list into the ndarray I get an empty array, thus voiding the whole analysis. The length of the ndarray is variable and it depends on the number of samples gathered. But I can get that easily with the 
    len(data_without_x)

Here is a snippet of the code that returns the empty list.

```
import numpy as np
import "other functions"

data, data_without_x = data_preparation.generate_sampled_pdf()
nodes_stats, k, list_of_list= result_som.get_number_k()

data_array = np.array(data_without_x)
whitened = whiten(data_array)
centroids, distortion = kmeans(whitened, int(k), iter=100000)
```

and this is what I get as output just saving in a simple log file:

```
___________________________
this is the data array[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
___________________________
This is the whitened array[[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 ..., 
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]
___________________________
```

Does anybody have a clue about what happens when I try to convert the list of list into a numpy.array?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `print(np.abs(data_array).sum())` to see if the array is really empty. The string representation doesn't show all of it.

Comment: the output to the above line is not zero is 2099918.5... this means it is not empty... then why I get such results?

Comment: Again, printing a NumPy array doesn't show the whole thing -- the non-zero elements are in the `...`. The NaNs are there because whitening can't handle all-zero rows and columns. You should remove those. (That will make k-means a lot faster, too.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is exactly how to convert a list of lists to an ndarray in python.  Are you sure your `data_without_x` is filled correctly?  On my machine:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
data_arr = np.array(data)

data_arr
array([[1,2,3,4],
       [5,6,7,8]])
```

Which is the behavior I think you're expecting

Looking at your input you have a lot of zeros...keep in mind that the print out doesn't show all of it.  You may just be seeing all the "zeros" from your input.  Examine a specific non zero element to be sure

Answer (score 0):

`vq.whiten` and `vq.kmeans` expect an array of shape `(M, N)`, where *each row* is an observation. So transpose your `data_array`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.vq as vq
np.random.seed(2013)    

data_without_x = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20.0, 1.0, 48.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1224.0, 125.5, 3156.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.5, 56.0, 41.5, 85.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1495.0,
        3496.5, 2715.0, 5566.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]


data_array = np.array(data_without_x).T
whitened = vq.whiten(data_array)

centroids, distortion = vq.kmeans(whitened, 5)
print(centroids)
```

yields

```
[[  1.22649791e+00   2.69573144e+00]
 [  3.91943108e-03   5.57406434e-03]
 [  5.73668382e+00   4.83161524e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.29763133e+00]]
```

Comment: Why do I have to make the T of data_array? In my configuration each row is an observation already, if I make the T of it then each column will be an observation, and that should not be the case isn't it?

Comment: If, as you say, "each row is an observation", then you only have two observations. Then it hardly makes sense to be clustering two rows. It seems more likely that you have 36 or more observations of planar points and are trying to find `k` clusters. If that interpretation is correct, then you must pass to `vk.kmeans` an array of shape (36,2), not (2,36).

Comment: Ok so basically I expressed myself incorrectly maybe. The point is that when I write "such as" it means that the observation that I am trying to cluster together are of that form, but this does not mean that only these two are the observations. The observation number is variable and it depends on other parameters, in the specific case there where 100K rows to cluster. The 36 is the number of dimensions  analyzed. So if for instance I have 75 observation I need to pass a [75,36] matrix instead of the [36,75]. Is this what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

use asarray function of numpy.
Its simple:
Ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks